# SQL Server Management Studio - optimizes my script in view desing incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a view something like (A AND B) OR (B AND (C OR (D AND K))), but SQL Server Management Studio rearranges it in a completely different incorrect way.

How can I disable this optimizer?

Regrads,

Comment: Could you show us what you type and what it gets changed to?

Comment: Show code please, no one can help without seeing what you're entering as the query

Comment: Only way is not to use the visual tools. The rearrangement is probably actually correct semantically  but can be annoying also I remember seeing a complaint that it also does this for expressions containing sub queries too leading to worse performance.

Comment: @JustAguy - Code isn't really needed (except to assess the incorrectness issue). In SSMS enter `SELECT 1 WHERE (A=1 AND B=1) OR (B=1 AND (C=1 OR (D=1 AND K=1)))` then select the text, right click and choose "Design Query in Editor". The query changes to `SELECT 1 AS Expr1 WHERE (A = 1) AND (B = 1) OR (B = 1) AND (C = 1) OR (B = 1) AND (D = 1) AND (K = 1)`. There is no way of stopping SSMS from performing this apart from simply avoiding the visual designers (they do have known bugs anyway)

Comment: You asked for the help, I would have helped and explained the method to the madness.  Don't bite the hand that feeds you...

Comment: @JustAguy I'm not the question asker.

Comment: I am sorry for not posting a proper sample, but Martin Smith caught the issue correctly. Indeed, probably, simplification is correct, but makes query much less readable. How do I avoid using visual designer? How do I create view without visual desiner? I clicked around, there is nothing obvious. Thank you to all who replied.

Comment: @user1700890 - To create a view just open a new query window. Then type `USE YourDB; GO; CREATE VIEW dbo.Foo AS SELECT A,B,C,D FROM YourTable`. To edit an existing one right click it in object explorer and choose the "Script View As -> Alter" option

Comment: Thank you, Martin Smith, you are a life saver! You should have posted it as the answer to the question!